# Axios post method is sending a object with my data as the key and empty value rather than the whole data object itself

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I made the frontend first and now I'm want to make the backend so I can connect to a database.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.send("hello");
});
app.post("/", function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
});
app.listen(3001, function () {
  console.log("listening on 3001");
});
```

And this is the request I'm making on my React frontend.

```
axios.post("http://localhost:3001/", JSON.stringify(note));
```

`note` is an object like `{title: "",content: ""}` the empty string gets filled out with submission data.

When I make the post request this is what gets logged in the console

```
{ '{"title":"test","content":"one"}': '' }
```

I had to use JSON.stringify() to show what's being passed through but without it, my output is {}

When my object is posted it becomes the key of an object with empty values.

What I want to do is simply send the whole object like so

```
axios.post("http://localhost:3001/", note);
```

so that in the backend I can tap into the values by doing `req.body.title` and `req.body.content`.

Comment: `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));` - you are not sending data in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format, you are sending JSON - so you need to use the appropriate body parser for the latter as well.

Answer (score 0):

The necessary body-parsing middleware is [`express.json()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.json):

```js
app.post("/", express.json(), function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

This requires that the request has the header `Content-Type: application/json`.